# How to select a file in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How could I choose a file after clicking a select button? When I click the select button it should be opened a popup window that I can select the file from my harddisk.

```
-(IBAction)select:(id)sender{
    NSOpenPanel* dlg =[NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [dlg setCanChooseFiles:YES];
    [dlg setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** (after code posted):

You are not actually opening the panel, so you need something like:

```
NSInteger button = [dlg runModal];
if (button == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton)
{
    NSURL *chosenURL = [[dlg URLs] objectAtIndex:0];
    // Do something with chosen file
}
```

Comment: I did but the panel did not opened. I will post my code see what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** : The `NSOpenPanel` can only be `run modally`.So u `need` `[YourNSOpenPanelObject runModal]`.

Refer [NSOpenPanel](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSOpenPanel) link.

---

Use `NSOpenPanel`. Example to select `NSImage` with `filteration` is given below:

```
NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
//[openDlg setCanChooseFiles:YES];
//[openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
[openDlg setPrompt:@"Select"];
NSArray* imageTypes = [NSImage imageTypes];
[openDlg setAllowedFileTypes:imageTypes];
//[openDlg setAllowsOtherFileTypes:NO];
[openDlg beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result){
 NSArray* files = [openDlg filenames];
 NSData *imgData;
 for(NSString* filePath in files)
 {
        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
        NSImage *img;
        if(url)
        { 
            img = [[NSImage alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
            imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            [url release];
        }
        if(img)
        {
            imgSubCategoryView.image = img; 
            [img release];
        }
        else
        {
            imgSubCategoryView.image = nil;
            NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc]init];
            [alert setMessageText:@"Application Message"];
            [alert setAlertStyle:NSInformationalAlertStyle];
            [alert setInformativeText:@"Select Only Image"];
            [alert beginSheetModalForWindow:_window
                              modalDelegate:self didEndSelector:nil contextInfo:nil];
        }
 }
}];
```

Comment: I edited my question and posted my code could please help me why the window does not open after clicking the button?